# How to change app.py variable with HTML button?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

How do I add or subtract 1 from the variable num ( in flask route) with an HTML button?

So when I click the button it change the var to 1 and refresh the page to show the new value

```
@app.route('/')
def note():
    num = 1
    return render_template('home.html', num=num)
```

Comment: That won't work, because each refresh num will reset to 1, you could save the value to a database.

Comment: Can you do it using js?

Comment: You can do it using jquery and another route to get this variable from a database or something like that

Answer (score 0):

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = 'BAD_SECRET_KEY'

@app.route('/')
def home():
    if session['num'] > 0:
       session['num'] = session['num']
else:
    session['num'] = 0

if request.method == 'GET':
    session['num'] += 1 

num = session['num']

return render_template('home.html', num=num)
```

home.html

```
<form>
   <input type="submit" name="count_button" value="count">
</form>

<h1>The count is: {{num}}</h1>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted was **impossible** without a full page refresh. So I wrote the component in **JavaScript**. I Found this the wrong way. thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example:

```py
num = 0
@app.route('/')
def note():
    num = num + 1
    return render_template('home.html', num=num)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Any feedback maybe?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I have done the way you did it above. The problem is I want to alter the num variable from the html jinja2 template

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by that... Wouldn't this example do that? you're sending num=num, what's the expected Output?